# Javascript CORS GET request blocked or invalid

Tags: javascript, api, cors

I'm struggling for quite some time already with issuing a simple GET request to a 3rd party REST Api. I've read a bit of tutorials and SO questions but I just can't get it to work. I am getting one of two errors

**Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)**

or (if via https)

**Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost:8433' is therefore not allowed access.**

About 2nd message: Is it just a problem with the server not supporting CORS?

My code:

```js
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'https://inspirehep.net/record/451647?of=recjson&ot=recid,number_of_citations,authors,title'; //http or https, tried both

/* 
   doing sth with response here like populate dropdown etc.
*/

xmlHttp.open('GET', url, true);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Cache-Control");
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
xmlHttp.send();
```

Whole app is running on node.js server (localhost) and the script above is included as separate file in .html view.

I can correctly get json response from web-browser, fiddler, postman etc. for this API. I also tried different APIs (e.g. Openweather API) thinking that it's the problem with server configuration, but the result was the same.

I would be thankful for any help - maybe i'm just misunderstanding something about CORS.

Comment: CORS headers are not something you can send in your request. The server has to respond with the headers.

Comment: "Is it just a problem with the server not supporting CORS?" — Yes.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I thought that might be the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot set headers from the browser, if the target url runs on your server or a server that you manage and that server runs nodejs you can use cors https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors, however, if this is a third party url and it doesn't not allow CORS, then you should make the request from the your back-end through configuring a proxy from your server to third party server, that should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer on CORS with nodejs is most likely right, but I want to suggest that you run a test to make sure your code works fine as well.

Try with Chrome and download an extension to allow CORS. This way you will test the functionality first before trying the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party...

http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ is great, but you don't need it if you are using XMLHttpRequest() and a GET method. Simply exclude your header requests...

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open( "GET", YOURURL );
//OMIT THESE...
  //xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
  //xhr.withCredentials = true;
  //xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', _contenttype );
  //xhr.setRequestHeader( 'CrossDomain', 'true' );
//....

xhr.addEventListener( 'load',  function () {
       xhr.responseJSON = JSON.parse( xhr.responseText );
       alert( xhr.responseJSON);
});

xhr.onerror = function(e) { 
      alert("Ajax request error");
};

xhr.send( JSON.stringify({}) );
```